# Whether Multiple Master Page can use in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know whether multiple master pages can be used in MVC 3. please give me a example how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many master pages (Layout) as you want. Add them under `Views -> Shared` folder and mention the layout which you want to use in your view as

`Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_myLayout.cshtml";`